# Create a summary table of frequency of boolean value in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with some hospital data and I am struggling with grouping/pivot tables in order to summarise the data in the way I need to present it

I have a dataframe of individuals with their age as a category (i.e. 20-25, 25-30), an intervention (boolean value) and the outcome as a category (discharged home, died, still in hospital).

I am trying to arrange the data like the example below:

```
|---------------------|------------------------------------------------------------------|
|                     |                            Outcomes                              |
|---------------------|------------------------------------------------------------------|
|    Age Categories   |   Fraction when intervention is true (row total as denominator   |
|---------------------|------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

I have read multiple tutorials on pivot tables/groupby etc but haven't been able to find the answer to my problem.

Comment: provide an MRE.

Comment: @ombk it helps to provide a link so the user know you are talking about a [mcve]. This can be done with the shortcut `[mcve]`

Comment: This [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) might be a good place to start